# How to connect Odoo with postgres (which is running on other server)

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, python-3.x, odoo-10, postgresql-9.6

I want to connect odoo 10 with the postgresql (which is running on other server). Is it possible ? If, yes! then please do help me out by posting step by step procedure or any sort of tutorial link (because I'm beginner). For now, I'm using odoo10 and postgresql-9.6 For different servers I'm using two different virtual machines (one is for odoo & other is for postgresql)

Here, I'm using two virtual machines 216.200.116.8 (for odoo) & 216.200.116.174 (for postgresql). I'm able to access postgresql from 216.200.116.8 remotely.

Here is my /etc/odoo.conf

[image]

Here is my /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf

[image]

Here is my /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf

[image]

After everything is configured I'm running odoo server from /opt/odoo/odoo10.0/odoo-bin

I've encountered this error! The detailed error says:

[image]

[image]

Odoo ver : 10 & postgresql ver : 9.6

Database User :postgres

password for postgres: passwd

Help needed! Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you connect to postgres from the odoo machine

Comment: Just to make sure: you're starting Odoo including -c /path/to/config? In your case  /opt/odoo/odoo10.0/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo.conf otherwise your config won't be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you must change the user in the database, `odoo` doesn't allow "postgres" as the user, you must create an "odoo user" to connect the application to the database like this:

```
db_user: odoo
db_password: yourpassword
```

Then in the `postgres.conf` file you must change this line:

`listen_adresses = 'localhost'`

I can't remember if something must be changed in the `.hba`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in `pg_hba.conf` file

In IPV4 section , you need to replace 1 line with below change.

```
host    all     all    0.0.0.0/0    trust
```

This is for first line in IPV4 section.

After Restart PostgreSQL , you can connect.